# How to put a path param to the request body before validation happens?

Tags: jax-rs, quarkus

I got the following test entity:

```
public class Test {
    public String id;
    public String name;
}
```

My test resource looks like this:

```
@Path("test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TestResource {
    @Path("{id}")
    @POST
    public Test test(@Valid Test test){
        return test;
    }
}
```

If I do  a POST with `name` as request body, I will end up with an entity which has a name but no id set. If I want to have set the id, I define a `@PathParam("id") String id` and then set the id with `test.id = id`. That is what I am using right now.

In this case, if I put a `@NotNull` constraint to the ID, the validation fails.

How can I 'put' the parsed ID to the request body, before the validation is happening? Ideal, not manually in any case.

Comment: I am almost certain this is not possible currently. Could you open a feature request for this on the quarkus github project?

Comment: @geoand Yes, sure! :) Would be nice to have this feature as it would save many code in my project.

Comment: Great, pleas ping me on the issue (`geoand` on github as well)

Comment: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6253

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `@NotNull` annotation and ensure that no ID is given from the POST request. And in your GET endpoints ensure that the field is not `null`, probably with an own annotation. I did this with my own annotation `@TestIdNull(false)`.

In your code you would place the annotation like this:

```
@Path("{id}")
@POST
public Test test(@TestIdNull(true) Test test){
    return test;
}
```

while the annotation interface looks quite simple:

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER,ElementType.TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = PetIdNullValidator.class)
public @interface TestIdNull {
  String message() default "Post request. ID value forbidden.";
  boolean value() default true;
  Class<?>[] groups() default {};
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

and the implementation would be

```
@Provider
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TestIdNullValidator implements ConstraintValidator<TestIdNull, Test> {

  private boolean switchNullCheck;

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void initialize(final TestIdNull constraintAnnotation) {
    switchNullCheck = constraintAnnotation.value();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public boolean isValid(final Test test, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (null == test) {
        return true;
    }

    context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
    context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("ENTER YOUR MESSAGE HERE").addConstraintViolation();

    return switchNullCheck ? test.id() == null : test.id() != null;
  }
}
```

On your "way back" (the GET methods) you must ensure the ID is not null with placing the annotation to your DTO. Code could look like this:

```
@TestIdNull(false)
final Test test = mapper.map(entity, Test.class);
```

I know it's not a very elegant way but your idea placing the ID in a POST first and then validate is not possible I'm afraid.

Comment: Can you please add a code snippet which clarifies your suggestion? As described in here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6253, I want to use the Path annotation to fill the given entity (from the post request). I want to use `@NotNull`, because that's a constraint from the database.

Comment: I added the code snippets. If the `@NotNull` annotation is a database constraint, you implemented your entity the wrong way. Use `@Column(nullable = false)` from javax.persistence instead. Or even more convenient: `@Id` (I guess the ID field is your PK on the DB table?). What I show up here is for `@NotNull` in a DTO.

Comment: The use case is to copy the id of the path to request body before the validation happens. So the question is not specific about the validation!. I attached a reproducer in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6253, so maybe this helps to understand the use case better.

Comment: Hmm I see. Why would you ever do that? Is the POST for creation or is it for updating the resource? In case of creation an ID client-side is frobidden in POST.

Comment: First example: We have some core data, which we import via POST requests with a fixed it. Second example: If a user creates some data, the path of the POST request is /users/{id}/something. The POST body data does not require a ID, but the entity itself does and therefore it would be handy to copy the id from the path to the entity.

Comment: So you mean the FK from "Something" to "User"? Well, as I already mentioned, in entity classes you never need `@NotNull`. You can ensure it with `@Column(nullable=false)` or a key annotation. When you annotate the path variable `{id}` with `@NotNull` and your entity with `@Column(nullable=false)` then what are you worrying about? And your first example (core data with a fixed ID) sounds like a POST violation; use PUT instead.

Comment: Imagine I have a food which an user can own. The food has a foreign key `userId`. The POST request is `/users/{userId}/foods`. The body does *not* include the `userId`. The request body looks like `{"name": "Apple"}`. So it does not include the `userId`. The POST method (in Java) has a parameter `Food food` which should be annotated with `@NotNull`. The entity itself has a field `String userId`. So if the validation happens, it will fail because the `userId` was not provided in the request body. I simple want to copy the `userId` from the path to the request body, before validation happens.

Comment: Yes, I understand this from your last description. Once again: What you have in mind is neither possible nor do you need it. You have 2 options: You create a Food DTO without a `userId` field which serves as the body for validation on the endpoint's method parameter. Then you map the DTO to your entity. Or you use the entity only without the `NotNull` annotation.
And BTW: I'm not too sure about Quarkus but in Spring you don't set the ID as value anymore. You should get you `User` entity first and then call
`foodEntity.setUser(userEntity)` for setting the FK.

Comment: We are using the fist approach but I want this to happen automatically (from the path param). I also think this is not possible.